# `keyof` for enum names in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Given a module like:

```
export module Common.Enums {
  export enum Enum1 { Item = 0 }

  export enum Enum2 { Item = 0 }

  export enum Enum3 { Item = 0 }
}
```

I would like to define an interface with a string property restricted to the name of one of the enums, something like:

```
interface Test {
    enumName: keyof Common.Enums; // <<< This doesn't work, but something like that is needed
    enumName2: 'Enum1' | 'Enum2' | 'Enum3'; // <<< This does work, but is undesirable

}
```

However - there are a lot of enums (they get generated), so I don't want to have to hard-code `'Enum1' | 'Enum2' | 'Enum3'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Common.Enums` is a value that exists at runtime, not a type.  To get the type of a value, you can use the [`typeof` type query operator](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/types-from-extraction/#typeof):

```
interface Test {
    enumName: keyof typeof Common.Enums;  // "Enum1" | "Enum2" | "Enum3"
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAWwgEwK4BthwMIQUgOwDoBRA1BAZzgG8AoOOUSWJ8hOMigRlrgEkYwDgF44ABjgBfOgybho8YO07sATH0HC4YyTLnNFbCqooBmTUNETpdfQEsCQqADMAhgGMsAFWCV49IyMyhQAcm4IwABccADWwACeEC5wMAlgwMk4eISk7JQA3HByjAD0pXAAFGBQEBmwCQCUcL7+RCEI4ZExAERcCNw9cAA+cH3qQ6Pj5j12skA)